# Having a Python if statement syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on some python code but its giving me a syntax error in the second 'if statement'. When I run it, it highlights `quadpos`. What seems to be the problem?

```
print(' Hello, press enter to continue')

print('What is your A value?')      # Asking for the A value
myA = input()
myA = int(myA)
print('What is your B value?')      # Asking for the B value
myB = input()
myB = int(myB)
print('What is your C value?')      # Asking for the C value
myC = input()
myC = int(myC)

quad = ((myB * myB) - (4 * myA * myC))
if int(quad) < int(0):
   print('Cannot process Value')
else:
   quad2 = (int(quad)**(1/2.0))
   if int(myA) > int(0):
       quadneg = ((int(-myB) - int(quad2)) / (2 * myA) 
       quadpos = ((int(-myB) + int(quad2)) / (2 * myA)
       print(int(quadneg))
       print(int(quadpos))
   else:
          quad3 = ((int(-myB) * int(-myB)) + int(quad2)) / (2 * myA) 
          print (int(quad3))
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the line 21 and 22 according to your attached picture

```
print( int( quardneg) )
print( int(quardpos) )
```

followed by else statement

The syntax of if else statements are :

```
If condition:
     Code...
Else 
    Code ..
```

You are doing:

```
 If condition:
     Code
 Code -- Error is here
 Else 
     Code.
```

You can't put the code in the same indentation of `if` statement, if you do so then you have to replace `else` by next `if`.

Comment: It seems to be giving me the syntax error in the line 20. Even after the indentation has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a missing bracket.

```
quadneg = ( (int(-myB) - int(quad2)) / (2 * myA) )
quadpos = ( (int(-myB) + int(quad2)) / (2 * myA) )
```